# Jelastic PHP Container not updated and not compatible with new Visual Studio Code Version

Tags: php, linux, visual-studio-code, jelastic

I'm using Jelastic native PHP server by Infomaniak.ch for my website.

Actually with the new version of Visual Studio code (1.86), they updated the minimal dependencies Version (like glibc 2.28).

I don't find any way to update my Linux or glibc version of my native Jelastic PHP environnments.

Does someone have the same problem ? Was someone able to update their PHP version without changing the PHP container to a non-native jelastic PHP-container ?

Contact Infomaniak to have more information. They apparently don't want to update the Linux server of their native environments docker and ask me to create my own docker.